# Spark | Could not create FileClient | read json | scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I am trying to read a json file in windows local machine using spark and scala. I have tried like below :

```
object JsonTry extends App{

  System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutils")
  
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("some-config", "some-value")
    .appName("App Name")
    .getOrCreate();

  val res = sparkSession.read.json("./src/main/resources/test.json")

  res.printSchema()
}
```

Json file which is under resource folder looks like below :

```
{"name":"Some name"}
```

But i am getting an exception when I run this main class :

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Could not create
> FileClient

Screenshot attached :

[image]

To my surprise this piece of code is working, but i am looking to read json from file directly.

`val res = sparkSession.read.option("multiline", true).json(sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("{\"name\":\"name\"}")))`

Please let me know what is causing this issue, as I am not getting any solution .

Answer (score 0):

I tried to read a json file in a similar way but I didnt face any problem,
You may try this too .

```
object myTest extends App {

val spark : SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                          .appName("MyTest")
                          .master("local[*]")
                          .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
val jsonDataDF = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/Users/gp/Desktop/temp/test.json")
jsonDataDF.show() 

}
```

Output -

[image]

I/P Data (JSOn) ->

[image]

Do let me know if I understood your question properly or not ?

Comment: still facing the same issue. Somehow this is working : `sparkSession.read.option("multiline", true).json(sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("{\"name\":\"name\"}")))`